# Is there a way to record the objects created at java application startup using JProfiler attach on wait mode?

Tags: jprofiler

I would like to profile a Java application start up and understand what are the objects created and what causing GC using JProfiler

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Session Startup" dialog that is shown when you start the profiling session in JProfiler, there is a "Initial recording profile" setting.

[image]

You can add a profile that records allocations by clicking on the "Configure" button

[image]